# Building the SeeingWand on Raspberry Pi Zero and have coding issues

Tags: python

This is my first posting, so please forgive any lack of decorum

I am building a SeeingWand as outlined in MagPi issue #71.
I have installed and tested all the HW.  Then install the python code, the original; code was python2.7, I have update the code to run under python3, but get a strange error when i run the code:

The system displays that the http module does not have a .client attribute.

The documentation says it does.  I have tried .client and .server attributes both give the same error.  What am i doing wrong?

I have tried several coding variations and several builds of the raspberry OS (Raspbian) mostly give the same errors

```
import picamera, http, urllib, base64, json, re
from os import system
from gpiozero import Button
```

## CHANGE {MS_API_KEY} BELOW WITH YOUR MICROSOFT VISION API KEY

```
ms_api_key = "{MS_API_KEY}"
```

## camera button - this is the BCM number, not the pin number

```
camera_button = Button(27)
```

## setup camera

```
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
```

## setup vision API

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': ms_api_key,
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'visualFeatures': 'Description',
})
```

## loop forever waiting for button press

while True:

```
camera_button.wait_for_press()
camera.capture('/tmp/image.jpg')
```

---

```
body = open('/tmp/image.jpg', "rb").read()

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPsConnection('westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/vision/v1.0/analyze?%s"%params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    analysis=json.loads(response.read())
    image_caption = analysis["description"]["captions"][0]["text"].capitalize()
# validate text before system() call; use subprocess in next version
    if re.match("^[a-zA-z ]+$", image_caption):
        system('espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s120 "' + image_caption + '"')
    else :
        system('espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s120 "i do not know what i just saw"')

    conn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print (e.args)
```

The system displays an error stating that the http module does not have a .client attribute.

The documentation says it does.  I have tried .client and .server attributes both give the same error.  What am i doing wrong?

Expected results are:
when i push button 1 I expect the camera to take a picture 
when i push button 2 i expect to access MSFT Azure to identify the picture using AI
the final output is for the Wand to access the audio hat and describe what the Wand is "looking" at.

Comment: I had to ask Google what a "SeeingWand" is... interesting project, I am curious to know how smart it is. Point it at something really outrageous.

Comment: I have a friend who has managed to get it working and he says 80% of the time the wand is spot on.... but the other 20% of the descriptions are pretty hilarious.  I am still trying to figure out why my kit won't work ;-( when it does I let you know how it goes for me.

Comment: If you are seeing new errors and search doesn't return any existing answers, you could post another question about the new errors. I think my answer will get you past the immediate issue you described here, but i would suggest that you reconsider your approach: trying to update a non-trivial sized package (which i think is pretty much all the packages you are using) from Python 2 --> Python 3 is not easy... Unless there is a really good reason why you must use Python 3, I would just install Python 2 and use that. Your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an import like this:

```
import http.client
```

Edit: `http` is a Python package. Even if the package contains some modules, *it does not automatically import those modules* when you import the package, unless the `__init__.py` for that package does so on your behalf. In the case of `http`, the `__init__.py` is empty, so you get nothing gratis just for importing the package.

Comment: That worked!!, the SeeingWand still doesn't work, but that got rid of the http module does not have a .client attribute error.    Thanks